# How to Apply IF Where Condition in Laravel Collation

Tags: laravel, collect, laravel-6

I need to collect my ticket sections from the array event, and my condition is

```
if 'custom_times' == 'yes'
```

then pick up ticket section with only
         `section_end_time < current date`

**Sample array Format**

```
 {"event_id":1,"ticket_type":"event", "custom_times":"yes",.....,"ticket_section":[{"section_id":1,"section_end_time":"2019-10-10 12:12:12",..... }]}
```

**Query**

```
$ticket_sections = collect($event->ticket_sections)->map(function($sections) {
return $sections;
})->where('ticket_type', 'event')
  ->where('hide_online', 'no')
  ->when('custom_times' == 'yes', function($query){
     return $query->where('section_end_time', '<' ,$event->current_date_time);
  });
```

But the above query not return the actual result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've confused the collection with the query builder.

The [when](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-when) method of the collection needs a boolean value to work and can't work with a condition on the collection members.

Here's how you can do what you need:

```php
$ticket_sections = collect($event->ticket_sections)
  ->where('ticket_type', 'event')
  ->where('hide_online', 'no')
  ->filter(function($section) use ($event) {
     return $section->custom_times !== 'yes' 
          || $section->section_end_time < $event->current_date_time;
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  Iam new to laravel that's why this happens...,  I will try your answer.